# Redmine - one project one vhost

Tags: apache, redmine, vhosts

I use redmine 1.2.2

Let's say I own **project1.net** and **project2.net** pointing on the same physical server.

I already have **bugs.project1.net** pointing on my redmine installation's home.

Here is my current config for bugs.project1.net

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName bugs.project1.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/redmine.log

  <Directory /var/www/redmine>
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I'd like to have **bugs.project1.net** and **bugs.project2.net** pointing on the corresponding redmine projects

How can I change the apache configuration for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

I could use a Redirect directive to point to each project, but it wouldn't work when you click some issue, for example. You cannot isolate a project inside redmine on a separated apache vhost AFAIK.